# A generalization of scrolls

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

As far as I can see, scrolls are constructed by means of rational curves. Is it possible a generalization with algebraic varieties of arbitrary dimension?

Comment: I think the notion you are looking for is the join of two varieties. This is discussed in Harris' *First Course*.

Comment: Another generalization is a projectivization of a vector bundle.

Comment: @TabesBridges: the join of two varieties $X$ and $Y$ consists of all the lines joining $X$ and $Y$, I want only the lines of type $P,P^{\phi}$, with $\phi$ an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.